# Length of array passed as an argument to a function

Tags: arrays, bash, arguments

I need to pass an array as an argument to a function (that is fine) and then get its length (I don't get that to work).

Working example:

```
function foo {
 declare -a idn=("${!1}")
 echo "idn=${idn[@]}"
 n=${#idn[@]}
 echo "n=$n"
}

identifier=(a b c d e)
echo "len is ${#identifier[*]}"
echo foo
foo identifier[*]
```

The output of that is:

```
len is 5              #that is OK
foo
idn=a b c d e
n=1                   #should be 5
```

Length outside function is ok, but it is not inside the function.

I am using GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original script should work by just changing last line to :

```
foo "identifier[@]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use a **-n**ameref variable like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo ()
{
  # If argument 1 is not an array, return an error
  [ "${!1@a}" = 'a' ] || return 2

  # Make idn a nameref variable referrencing the array name from argument 1
  declare -n idn="$1"

  echo 'idn:' "${idn[@]}"
  n=${#idn[@]}
  echo 'n:' "$n"
}

identifier=(a b c d e)
echo "len is ${#identifier[*]}"
echo foo
foo identifier
```

Or pass array elements as value:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

foo ()
{
   declare -a idn=("${@}")

   echo 'idn:' "${idn[@]}"
   n=${#idn[@]}
   echo 'n:' "$n"
}

identifier=(a b c d e)
echo "len is ${#identifier[*]}"
echo foo
foo "${identifier[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the individual arguments of the array `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` to your function, use `foo "${identifier[@]}"`. Then in the function you can use `$#` to get the number of arguments.

Or if you want to pass the name of the variable to your function, you could use a local `nameref` variable `idn` which
is a reference to the `identifier` array.

```
foo() {
  echo "n=$#"
}

foo2() {
  local -n idn=$1
  echo "n=${#idn[@]}"
}

identifier=(a b c d e)
echo "len is ${#identifier[*]}"
foo "${identifier[@]}"
foo2 identifier
```

Output:

```
len is 5
n=5
n=5
```